# boost::filesystem::exists segfault on linux

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, filesystems

The function boost::filesystem::exists() segfault on my Kubuntu and I don't know why.

Here is my function:

```
if (!boost::filesystem::exists("./sthg"))
{
  // ....
}
```

I check with valgrind and he tells me the error is in xstat.c:35 and the error is "Syscall param (file_name) contains uninitialised byte(s)."

Here is my compilation line:

```
g++ ... -o ... -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

**EDIT 1:**

the function that calls the function that creates the directory:

```
void TCPConnection::enable(void)
{
    try {
        StaticTools::CreateFolder("./clients");
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the function that creates the directory:

```
void StaticTools::CreateFolder(std::string const& path)
{
    if (!boost::filesystem::exists(path)) {                                                                                                                         
       if (!boost::filesystem::create_directory(path)) {
          throw (std::runtime_error("..."));
       }
    }                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Valgrind log:
http://pastebin.com/gbzFDDNg

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the string you _actually_ passed to `boost::filesystem::exists` was invalid.  The second most likely explanation is that your Boost installation is either self-inconsistent or inconsistent with the core C++ runtime library.  To help us figure out which of these two it is, please provide a [minimal, _complete_ verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than just a fragment.

Comment: Other things that you could tell us that would help: the _exact, unedited_ output of `dpkg-query -W -f '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Version} ${Package}\n' g++* libstdc++* boost* libboost* | grep '^ii' | column -t` ; whether you have installed any software (especially boost or the compiler) manually instead of via the package manager; and the full stack trace you got from `valgrind`.

Comment: By the way, it is almost always a mistake to check whether a file exists, because it has an inherent race: in between the check and the action you take based on the check, some other program may create or delete the file, invalidating the check.  Instead, just go ahead and do the thing you want to do with the file, and check whether that _fails_.  (The system primitive [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) has an option `O_EXCL` which is very useful for this.  Unfortunately, neither stdio nor iostreams exposes that option.)

Comment: thanks for your answers, indeed, I just delete the exists() verification and it work fine, but it's weird ... if you are still interested by this problem, i will edit my question and add the log you asked.
- The string is valid, I passed it by copy and not by reference for the test
- I have installed boost with the apt-get install command, same for g++
- My boost::asio works so i think it's good for the installation ?

Comment: Please post the actual code that caused the error. We can't find the bug in code we can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If boost::filesystem's exceedingly unclear documentation means what I think it means, then the function that creates the directory should simply read

```
void StaticTools::CreateFolder(std::string const& path)
{
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(path);
}
```

because, if `create_directory` returns without throwing an exception, then the directory does exist.  (The return value only tells you whether the directory *has just been created* versus *already existed as a directory*. You probably don't care.)

2) If the call to this function really truly was

```
    StaticTools::CreateFolder("./clients");
```

with the string literal "./clients" as the argument, *and* "Syscall param stat(file_name) contains uninitialised byte(s)" really truly was the *very first* error emitted by `valgrind`, then, I regret to say, you may be in the unfortunate case of boost being inconsistent with the C++ runtime library.  Specifically, I think your `libstdc++.so` may be defaulting to C++11 `std::string` whereas your `libboost_filesystem.so` is expecting C++98 `std::string`, or vice versa.  There is no good way for you to fix this; the Kubuntu people responsible for boost and/or the C++ runtime have to do it.  The path of least effort is probably to stop using boost.  That is not a joke.